# Incorrect Color Displayed on Bottom Navigation Bar of My Device

Tags: android, kotlin

I needed to set the 'setDecorFitsSystemWindows' to 'false' in my activity, which resulted in incorrect margins for the views within the activity. To rectify this, I programmatically added a margin to one of my views and executed the following code to adjust the other views:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView) { view, windowInsets ->
        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        view.updatePadding(bottom = insets.bottom)
        WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
    }
```

However, I'm now facing an issue where the bottom navigation bar (I'm unsure of the exact term) on my device is white, while it's black in the rest of the app. Is there a way to revert it to the default color? Alternatively, is there a different approach I could use to resolve the margin issue?

This is what I think is the Bottom Navigation Bar of My Device:
[image]

Thank you in advance.